# Binary Search multidimensional array in string

Tags: java, search, binary-search

Actually, I'm working on my homework assignment. And, I'm really stuck.

I need to learn Java the right way. My teacher hasn't been teaching us about Binary Search with String. So, I had to end up at least few hours researching about the topic.

I need some simple explanation and code.

**for example** :

```
String[][] data={{"John abc","123"},{"Nike cbd","321"}};
```

I need input for searching '*John*' and it will show the output '*John abc, 123*'.

Can somebody suggest some guidance on the principles of binary search?

Comment: You should look for a tutorial online. It will do a better job explaining this than any of us will

Answer (score 3):

Strings can be sorted and compared just like numbers, using alphabetic string comparison. let's assume only English for simplicity, "ABD" is bigger than "ABC" and so forth.

So any binary search algorithm example that you find for numbers will work on strings, provided that the list you have is sorted of course. the idea is simple of course - narrow your candidates in half for each iteration until you find the right one.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.binarySearch` is currently supported for one dimensional array.

So you have to narrow down your array to one dimension then call `binarySearch()`.

Example:

```
for(String[] oneDimension : multiDimension ){
   Arrays.sort(oneDimension);
   Arrays.binarySearch(oneDimension, 'search-field');
}
```